# How can I solve this UTF-8 problem during openstack installation?

Tags: utf-8, openstack

I am trying to install openstack on an VM ubuntu server.

I git clone the devstack repository and I am launching the ./stack.sh file

However I have this error. I guess it is a simple utf-8 problem but I don't knwow how how to resolve it.

```
File "/home/stack/devstack/tools/outfilter.py", line 104, in <module> sys.exit(main)) File "/home/stack/devstack/tools/outfilter.py", line 98, in main outfile.write(ts_line.encode('utf-8'))

UnicodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 110-112: surrogates not allowed
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I solve an UTF-8 problem while installing openstack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60817282/how-can-i-solve-an-utf-8-problem-while-installing-openstack)

Comment: Is this the same problem as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60817282/how-can-i-solve-an-utf-8-problem-while-installing-openstack)? If so, just asking again doesn't really help.

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to edit the `/devstack/tools/outfilter.py` file and edit line 98 to add a `'surrogatepass'` parameter. This forces surrogate pairs to be resolved into the corresponding codepoint outside the BMP.

```
outfile.write(ts_line.encode('utf-8','surrogatepass'))
```

This got me through that error.

Comment: Thanks. Can I just re-run `stack.sh` afterwards or do I need to undo the installation up to that point and restart somehow? Or start a new VM from scratch?